# How to de-duplicate and modify a Big Query table?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table **A** that looks like this:

```
| origin |   food   |  category  |
----------------------------------
|  tree  |  apple   |    fruit   |
|  plant |  tomato  |    fruit   |
|  plant |  tomato  |  vegetable |
|........|..........|............|
|  plant |  tomato  |  vegetable |
```

I want to go through the table and for all `combinations of origin and food` that appear more than once, to concatenate their category like `fruit + vegetable` and delete the `standalone versions`. So the above table would be:

```
| origin |   food   |     category      |
-----------------------------------------
|  tree  |  apple   |    fruit          |
|  plant |  tomato  | fruit + vegetable |
|........|..........|...................|
```

I want to use `standardSQL` only. Any ideas how?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `STRING_AGG(DISTINCT)`.

```
with data as (
  select 'tree' as origin, 'apple' as food, 'fruit' as category union all
  select 'plant', 'tomato', 'fruit' union all
  select 'plant', 'tomato', 'vegetable' union all
  select 'plant', 'tomato', 'vegetable'
)
select origin, food, string_agg(distinct category,' + ') as category
from data
group by 1,2
```